# How do I make these errors go away?

Tags: c#, xaml

Can you tell me please what I need to change so that I won't get these errors anymore? I've duplicated an xaml+css class and that's why I get so many errors. I've attached an image to show you the errors. Someone recommended me to change something about these 2 things but I didn't quite understand, which is why I've decided to make a new post regarding this matter.

code c1.cs:

```
public partial class ImagesGrid : UserControl
```

code xaml c1.xaml:

```
x:Class="KinectInfoPortal.ImagesGrid"
```

[image]

EDIT1:

Code for C1.xaml.cs class:

```
public partial class ImagesGrid : UserControl
```

Code for ImageGrid.xaml.cs class:

```
public partial class ImagesGrid : UserControl
```

Code for C1.xaml:

```
x:Class="KinectInfoPortal.ImagesGrid"
```

Code for ImageGrid.xaml:

```
x:Class="Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.ControlsBasics.ImagesGrid"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the mistake:

Code for `C1.xaml.cs` class:

```
public partial class ImagesGrid : UserControl
```

Code for `ImageGrid.xaml.cs` class:

```
public partial class ImagesGrid : UserControl
```

It should be:

Code for `C1.xaml.cs` class:

```
public partial class C1: UserControl
```

Code for `ImageGrid.xaml.cs` class:

```
public partial class ImagesGrid : UserControl
```

You renamed file to **C1.xaml** but your class name is same as it is for **ImagesGird.xaml** user control due to which it is saying that its already defined changed class name as well.

You have two class with same name.

1) in **ImagesGrid.xaml** user control

2) in **C1.xaml** user control

which is obviuosly wrong.

Comment: You say `ImagesGird.xaml` - it should be `ImagesGrid.xaml`.

Answer (score 0):

When you duplicate a xaml/cs pair, you need to take care to change the name of the class in both the XAML file and the codebehind, basically the two lines of code you listed. Make sure that in the original class and in the new class, BOTH are different.

Comment: You're referring to the 4 things, right? take a look at my editing